# How many times runs a static object construction?

Tags: java, constructor, static

A little doubt with java and static variables. I have something like that, and the question is: MyObject() constructor runs only once or every time I create a new instance of MyClass?

```
public class MyClass{    
static MyObject obj = new MyObject();
...
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> MyObject() constructor runs only once or every time I create a new instance of MyClass?

It runs only once when the execution process(**class initialization** ) starts and shared (A single copy) across all the instances.

> A static initializer declared in a class is executed when the class is initialized (§12.4.2). Together with any field initializers for class variables (§8.3.2), static initializers may be used to initialize the class variables of the class.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.7

Comment: "Yes. Exactly." ? Nope... the line '''static MyObject obj = new MyObject();''' is executed only once when the class MyClass is loaded as mentioned by @Elliott-Frisch.

Comment: Could you get rid of "Yes" altogether? It's still misleading.

Comment: "It runs only once when the execution starts" is not equivalent to "when the class is initialized". The class is initialized when it is first used in the program and not when you start the program. In fact the constructor may not run at all, if the use of `MyClass` depends e.g. on the input.

Comment: I just edited my post, feel free to edit if you still find any misleading words.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it will only create it once! A static field is common among all your instances. Specifically, it's created when that `class` is initialized.

Answer (score 0):

It is executed only once during the class loading process.